# Replace each leading and trailing whitespace with underscore using regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, whitespace

```
var str = '  Some string    ';
var output = str.replace(/^\s|\s(?=\s*$)/g , '_');
```

The output should look like this

```
'___Some string____'
```

This code works fine for the trailing whitespaces but all the leading whitespaces are replaced with just one underscore.

The working php regex for this is:  `/\G\s|\s(?=\s*$)/`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not pretty, but gets the job done

```
var str = "  Some string    ";
var newStr = str.replace(/(^(\s+)|(\s+)$)/g,function(spaces){ return spaces.replace(/\s/g,"_");});
```

Comment: this is good work! And imo the only useful, since Js sadly does not support lookbehind.

Comment: Brilliant, I ***knew*** there was a clever way to create the replacement string.

Comment: This works! It's weird that the php pattern could not be adapted for JS.

Comment: It could not be adapted since JavaScript does not support lookbehinds.

Comment: +1 but the expression can be simplified to just: `/^\s+|\s+$/g`. There's no need for any of the capture groups (which aren't being used anyway - the first parameter passed to the callback function is the whole match: i.e. `spaces == $0`).

Answer (score 1):

This ***works*** but I don't like it:

```
var str = "  some string  ";
var result = str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, function(m) {
    return '________________________________________'.substring(0, m.length);
});
```

Or more flexibly:

```
var str = "  some string  ";
var result = str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, function(m) {
    var rv = '_',
        n;
    for (n = m.length - 1; n > 0; --n) {
        rv += '_';
    }
    return rv;
});
```

That can be refined, of course.

But I like [epascarello's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12895944/157247) better.

Comment: @epascarello: I refer you to my opening sentence. :-)

Answer (score 0):

another reg ex

```
var str = "  asdf       "
str.replace(/^[ ]+|[ ]+$/g,function(spc){return spc.replace(/[ ]/g,"_")})
//"__asdf_______"
```

Answer (score 0):

With [`String.prototype.repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) the accepted answer can now be improved to

```
function replaceLeadingAndTrailingWhitespace(text, replace) {
    return text.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, (spaces) => replace.repeat(spaces.length));
}
```